# OCaml unknown function for a signature

Tags: ocaml

First of all, does the following signature even exists (I personally think it may have errors), and, if it does, can you give me an example of matching code for it :

```
val f : 'a -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'b -> ('a -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'b) -> bool = <fun>
```

Comment: Yes you can write such a function. Could you give us more background? If it is a homework we should not give you a direct answer.

Comment: this question is quite twisted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's these two as examples:

```
let f a aa b a_aa_b = (aa a, a_aa_b a aa) = (a,b) (* forced by type inference *)
let f (a:'a) (aa: 'a -> 'a) (b: 'b) (c: 'a -> ('a -> 'a) -> 'b) = true (* explicitly stated *)
```

I can not remember that I've seen this signature before, so I do not know which function may have hide behind it.

Comment: Do you think even a `val f : 'a -> 'a` exists other than `let f x = x`?

Comment: As far as I know, it is the only total (and moreover, the only useful) function of this type. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945011/ocaml-is-there-a-function-with-type-a-a-other-than-the-identity-function for more information.